# WPF - XAML vs C#: Which (if any) has the best performance for creating UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Okay, this is quite an odd question so please forgive me if it sounds stupid.

Let's pretend for a moment that time is not an issue whatsoever, nor is human-comprehensibility of code, and an equal relative knowledge of both XAML and C# is had by this magic hypothetical party.

When it comes to creating the visual elements of a WPF application, how they act and generally all the things that XAML deals with by its nature - is there any actual performance advantage either XAML or C# have over one-another, were someone to attempt to try and assimilate as much XAML code into C# instead as is possible?

For example, avoiding using XAML styles altogether and instead just making custom-control classes with everything the style(s) did built in.

Does preference of either ever cause a performance impact on the given program?

Once again i apologize for this strange and mostly hypothetical question, but i can't seem to find many answers about either.

Thanks.

Comment: Google for `BAML`. In code behind it gonna be faster if you use loose xaml. BAML should be equally fast as your code. But as always - measure performance in your case.

Comment: Make it all in code, and enjoy watching the guy who separated his UI/Code (xaml/c#) with some MVVM and easier to maintain project get to market with his project long before you're even in beta. Performance differences are generally negligible if noticeable at all in my experience. Just my two cents, which I could a see a question like this soliciting many more lol.

Comment: C# (IL) is faster than XAML (BAML). Just not that convenient :P

Comment: Thanks, you've all been helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short:

- XAML is slowest
- BAML is faster
- IL has best performance

With slightly [better wording](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tomershamam/2007/05/25/compiled-xaml-baml-not-il/).